# jQuery product viewer

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im trying to build a simple, lightweight product viewer using jquery.

I have a default image that I want to dissapear when a thumb is clicked and replace the image in 'X' div.

Ive attached a fiddle if anybody can explain how this is done?

http://jsfiddle.net/BYuxR/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/sabri/gQyC4/

Try this

```
$('.thumbs a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.product-image').html( $('<img>').attr('src',$(this).attr('href')));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer.

http://jsfiddle.net/BYuxR/6/

Comment: Could you add a little bit of explanation here without needing the link?  At least a few sentences about the overall design of your solution would be great!